# How can I disable IntelliJ using the Gradle run task to run my code?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

After updating IDEA, every time I debug a class *in a new project only*, it seems to be using the Gradle run task to run my code (despite using an "Application" run configuration, not "Gradle"!):

```
6:40:27 AM: Executing task 'Test.main()'...

Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:49580', transport: 'socket'
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
Connected to the VM started by ':Test.main()' (localhost:49597). Open the debugger session tab

> Task :Test.main()
test
```

This is causing me many problems.

If I run tasks in an old project, it will just compile and run the code directly, without using Gradle. I compared all the settings in the two run configurations, and they're identical.

How can I disable this and prevent IntelliJ from creating this kind of run configuration when I just want a regular run configuration?

Comment: In the settings, go to `Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Runner`. Do you have the "_Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle_" checkbox selected?

Comment: Yes, I did! Unchecking that fixed it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 30):

In IntelliJ-IDEA 2019 the option was moved directly to **Gradle Settings** (`Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle`):

*Run tests using:* *Gradle* / *IntelliJ IDEA*

> [image: intellij gradle settings screen clip]

Answer (score 1):

**2022 Solution**

Basically, your intellij is building the project by running the gradle task everytime you run even a simple Application(a class having `main` method).

For the changing the setting that running `main method` should not build the project or basically run the gradle task.

**In IntelliJ IDEA 2022 version:**

IntelliJ IDEA => Preferences => Search `gradle` => Go to Gradle => Select Gradle for `Build and run using:` and `Run tests using:` as shown below:

[image]

Please remember to build or run gradle task separately in case when you update/change your `build.gradle`.