# Can't open a second instance of LibGDX game?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx, multiplayer, game-development

I'm currently developing a small multiplayer game for a university project using LibGDX in IntelliJ, but I'm running into an issue where I can't run more than one game at a time to test multiplayer functionality.

On executing the program the first time everything runs okay, but the second time I click run the process shows as running yet won't open a window until the first instance is closed. I've gone into the build/run configurations and checked the "Allow parallel run" option, but it didn't seem to do anything. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: this problem still exists on intelji community 2020 2.4

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your application is executed as a `Gradle Run Task`. The task will wait for the exit code of the process and block all other tasks including run tasks. I don't know if parallel execution of run tasks is possible, but this workaround worked for me:

1. Swap the `Build and run` option from Gradle to native IntelliJ IDEA as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60522292/2920861)
2. Now reconfigure your run configuration. If you are using Kotin you need to create a new one